# Mac OS X vpnd routing

Tags: mac, vpn, routing

I have a Mac running OS X 10.6.  I would like to connect to it remotely such that my requests from the remote machine appear to come from the aforementioned Mac (my database server access is restricted by IP address).  It has a public interface directly connected to the internet.  I configured vpnd such that the remote machines get an IP address in the 192.168.1.x range on this mac and can connect to it, but my traffic is not being routed to the public interface.

Am I approaching this problem the right way?  What do I need to do to achieve my goal of routing all traffic through this Mac?

Comment: are the network settings (especially gateway and mask) in the vpn client (the machine that connects to the vpn server) correct?

Comment: I did have them correct.  I ended up doing an SSH tunnel.